# How Can I Integrate Facebook With My Own Like Button

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-like

I have a like button on my own website, and I want it to function just like it currently does, with the additional feature that it also makes a post on the person's facebook timeline "John Smith liked this post on www.example.com" where www.example.com is my website.  How can this be achieved?

Facebook has documentation for how to put their own like button but I don't want theirs, I just want what I already have to have that one functionality.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are not allowed to use custom graphics for the Like Button, you MUST use their own one.

You can use og.likes to create your own Like Button: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/opengraph/action-type/og.likes

A message about the User having liked something shows up automatically on Facebook, you can't "autopost" it additionally. It would require to authorize a User with the `publish_actions` permission, and it will definitely not get approved by Facebook because the message parameter must be 100% User generated:

> Don't prefill captions, comments, messages, or the user message parameter of posts with content a person didn’t create, even if the person can edit or remove the content before sharing.

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/policy/

Comment: Hi two questions:

1) You are saying it is impossible to have my own like button automatically post to Facebook, I must use their like button.  Is this correct?

2) If I use their Like button I cannot change the graphics of it?

So basically, if I want it to post to facebook after a user likes a post on my site I have to use the facebook like button with their graphics?  Thanks

Comment: yes. but you can´t post to facebook after like on your own. facebook does that for you when you like something.

Answer (score -1):

If you know how to put their button on your page, you should also know how to put your own button on your page. It should be as easy as changing code between

```
<a href...>
```

and

```
</a>
```

I just googled 2 min and came up with this:

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button
```

It says: Use this URL in an iframe or as a link to your plugin.

```
http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fyoururl.com&width&layout=standard&action=like&show_faces=true&share=true&height=80
```

Just change yoururl.com to whatever it should like.

Comment: Right, but I don't know how to make my own button have the Facebook functionality, where it will post to the user's timeline

Comment: he wrote that he does have a like button on his website, so we can assume that he knows about the like button plugin ;)